# Rsnapshot with two alternating hard drives

Tags: 10.04, backup, rsnapshot

I am using ubuntu server 10.04 with rsnapshot;

I plan on alternating the backup external hdd every week.

The rsnapshot.conf:

snapshot_root /media/backup_disk_1/backup
no_create_root 1.

There is a hourly, daily, weekly and monthly cron job.

if I was to switch to the 2nd external hdd then I would need to setup another mount with it's UUID and mount to /media/backup_disk_2

then I would need to manually change the root location in rsnapshot.conf

snapshot_root /media/backup_disk_2/backup
no_create_root 1.

Is there an automated way to do this instead of changing the config file everytime I alternate between the hdd?

Will mounting both of the external hdd to /media/backup_disk_1 work?
So no matter which hdd I mount they will all mount to /media/backup_disk_1.

Answer (score 0):

Add a label to the file systems on both disks, with ext2:

```
e2label /dev/sdd1 BACKUP
```

Then in `/etc/fstab` add a line like:

```
LABEL=BACKUP  /media/backup_disk ext2 defaults 0 0
```

That way, when `autofs` detects a backup disk, it mounts it to the same place.